# C++ Threading CPU usage issue on older PC

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I need an expert's advice and opinion on thread usage. I have a simple "plugin" DLL which has 2-3 threads, each of them are started with **_beginthreadex()**.

A thread looks like this:

```
unsigned __stdcall Thread(void* pArguments)  
{  
    while ( true )  
    {
        // do something
        Sleep(3000);
    }
    _endthreadex( 0 );  
    return 0;  
}
```

Now, this thread does not have a high CPU usage, it works as expected on most new PC's, however I have discovered that on older PC's with dual core CPU's for example running 2-3 instances with this threading method it take a lot of CPU. I cannot explain myself why, and I don't know what to do.

I have tried **CreateThread()** also, but it does not make a change. Can someone please guide me how to create a thread that will run the same way on all PC's ? If I'm doing something wrong, then please explain to me what...

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your `Sleep` call is actually sleeping? If that returns immediately you're going to murder your thread and spin at 100% CPU.

Comment: why dont you want to use the cpu? tbh I find it a bit silly trying to minimize cpu usage of  a thread that does nothing but sleep.

Comment: Well it does call Sleep(), because I tested and it runs every X miliseconds I put in Sleep()...

Comment: @tobi303 - I need to reduce the usage, because as I said this works perfectly on newer PC's, but on older ones it affects the application that is running this DLL...

Comment: Use a profiler such as VTune or [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/) to see where all the CPU time is being spent, when running on an older CPU. (You probably have some timing-dependent race condition that only shows up on certain CPUs.)

Answer (score 0):

_beginthreadex is just a wrapper for CreateThread. And if you experience a high CPU usage then it's most likely a problem with your "do something" code that has nothing to do with the method initially used to create thread. Inspect your code with profiler and look for race conditions. Note that the snippet you posted is actually broken because the loop has no break and therefore method has unreachable code.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, so my "loop" is wrong ? I think you just found my problem.... :|

Comment: Well, if "do something" code that you omitted has a break somewhere then it isn't that broken. Note that there is also no need to call _endthreadex there because you will exit the thread routine anyway.

Comment: Well my "do something" does not have a break, that`s for sure... and I don`t really get it why I don`t need to call _endthreadex :/

Comment: Because when you exit thread routine the thread ends automatically.